# AJAX call opens php URL instead of return to callback execution

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a problem with AJAX callback:

1) In the login.html page I Use: $.post("login.php", formData, function(data) { }

2) in the login.php: echo $data='pass';

3) The problem -   On the submit event: the browser doesn't update the login.html callback. instead, it displays the login.php - a white screen with 'pass' or 'fail' string, instead of updating the login.html page

Comment: Do you use the `e.preventDefault();` in the event handler for the submit button?

Comment: Use `e.preventDefault()` or `return false` in the form submit handler

Comment: Thanks, used preventDefault. Now works fine !

Answer (score 0):

You need to use :

```
preventDefault();
```

---

```
$(function () {
    var yourForm = $('#yourform');
    yourForm.submit(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: yourForm.attr('method'),
            url: yourForm.attr('action'),
            data: yourForm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert('ok');
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: You're very welcome @user37975 :) If my answer helped you, please consider vote 1+ and accepting it as the correct answer by clicking the check mark in the middle of the vote arrows, tks !